# CSS url() path works if it is a web server but not when it is a local file?

Tags: html, css

I am trying out CSS's `shape-outside`:

```
shape-outside: url(image_file.png)
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/quzaorg0/3/

However, if I tried this example on the local machine (and used the path just as `pikachu300.png` for the HTML and CSS), and opened up the HTML file in Google Chrome or Firefox using the file system, then it wouldn't wrap the text around the image.

I had to start a local web server (any local web server, or simply by using `ruby -run -e httpd . -p 8080`), so that the CSS was able to get that image and wrap the text around the image.

The HTML and CSS had proper URL path, which is just the filename:

The CSS:

```
#intro-img { float: left; shape-outside: url(pikachu300.png); }
```

The HTML:

```
<img id="intro-img" src="pikachu300.png">
```

So the HTML could load the image, but the CSS couldn't load that image. It had to be served by a local web server.

I tried also

```
#intro-img { float: left; shape-outside: url(file://pikachu300.png); }
```

and it didn't work either. Why would the path **work for HTML but not CSS**, and how to make it work if it is tested as local files?

P.S. in the Developer Console, Network tab, the file cannot be loaded the second time. If I run a web server, the file can be loaded both times:

[image]

Comment: your css file, html file and image resides in same folder?

Comment: Are you sure that the file name is all lowercase? (Your webserver might ignore upper-/lowercase differences, and you filesystem probably doesn’t ignore them)

Comment: if the HTML can load the image like that, yes, they reside in the same folder

Comment: @t.niese yes for simplicity, I just renamed the file to `pic.png` so it is as simple as possible. Again, it worked from a web server from not for local files

Comment: Please check the Networktab of the developer console in your browser, to see which resource is not found,  maybe it is the whole css file that is not loaded.

Comment: Can you show your folder and file structure?

Comment: @t.niese done, it is shown at the bottom of the question

Comment: @SavanPadaliya there are only 2 files, `try.html` and `pic.png` (or the `pikachu300.png` earlier), all inside `/Users/userName/try/CSSNewFloat/` on a Mac

Comment: The file can be readable for you, but not for browser - check the file access :)

Comment: @V.Volkov it is the same `-rw-r--r--` on the Mac (when `ls -l` is done)

Comment: Got such error: Access to image at 'file:///home/****/pikachu300.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. And the list doesn't contain 'file'.. Do you have similar?

Comment: @V.Volkov I was trying them in different browsers and got distracted by the error "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser" and now I rechecked Chrome, it does have the error that you mentioned

Comment: I still blame CORS, even though only Chrome throws this error. I've found some explanation here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1481

Comment: @V.Volkov yes, it seems if HTML can access it, css `background` can access it, how come css `shape-outside` cannot access it?

Comment: Use quotation marks around the URL.

Comment: From the link above: "browsers treat similar local folder as cross-domain" (cross-origin), even though it's 2020 already :) And "the only way to reliably do local dev is to start a local server" - basically, the image for `shape-outside` gotta be accessible via http(s):, not file:

Comment: The difference seem to be: `background-image` gets the access to an image for displaying purposes, and `shape-outside` gets the access to transparent pixels - it requires cross-origin permissions or same origin, which `file:` is not.

Comment: @V.Volkov HTML and CSS background get the image info and transparency info, to draw on the screen. CSS `shape-outside` also gets the image info and transparency info, why is there any difference, I wonder

Comment: According to CORS, accessing an image and it's "insides", like, pixels positions, are different things. For example, adding an image to canvas with `drawImage` for further manipulations also demands CORS headers or similar origin.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem on a project of my own today.

This behavior is an idiosyncrasy having to do with file permissions via FTP vs. HTTP.  The solution is to run a local http server rather than using `file:///` when working locally.  Only under HTTP does the browser have permissions to read pixel transparency.

(@V.Volkov's comments on the original post give the solution, but I thought I would post the answer so that future users don't have to dig through the comments like I did.)

Answer (score 0):

I can See the problem. usually for relative path for current directory we refer it as `./dir/file` but for this case just omit `.` to become `/dir/file` this worked for me.

In other words use `url("/dir/file")` instead of `url("./dir/file")` once referring to local files in current directory in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

When using url() to point to your local file, if its within the same project folder, you need to refer it relative to where the CSS is located.

```
background-image: url('./imagename.jpg'); // Image is within the same folder with the CSS
background-image: url('./../imagename.jpg'); // Image is located outside the folder where css is located.
background-image: url('./../image/imagename.jpg'); // Image is located in another folder relative to the css folder.
```

For retrieving image in folder inside computer (outside the project scope), you can use direct path to that path instead. Right click on the image --> Property --> Location to get the path to the image. Make sure you change the path's \ to / on the URL.

```
background-image: url('C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/{imagename}'); // Image is located inside the Downloads folder
```

Comment: `url(pikachu300.png)`, `url(./pikachu300.png)`, `url("/Users/userName/try/CSSNewFloat/pikachu300.png")` all did not work.

Comment: @nopole Are you using this for shape-outside property? URL on background-image works as expected. Tested with shape-outside, it indeed doesn't work as you described. You might wanna combine background-image with shape-outside property together (works in the same manner as providing image src with shape-outside inside style on Img tag) if you want to use CSS as mean to provide image source.